# function keys for volume not working properly in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: sound, volume-control

When using the volume buttons (+, -, mute) they are reacting weirdly. When I press the key for increasing the volume a bit, it'll go to the maximum automatically and when I decrease the volume, it'll automatically go to 0.

Volume control with the mouse works fine.

The buttons are working and get recognized:

Checked with keyboard system settings tool: they get recognized by the tool both from the laptop directly as well as from my USB keyboard.

Who can help?

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Comment: @QuinnCulver Do you have vanilla installation of Ubuntu? Or added more Desktop Environments DE to it?

Comment: Yes I have vanilla @user.dz.

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1302885)

Open terminal and run the commands:

```
 gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
 gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down
 gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute
```

hope it work .

Comment: Please comment if not worked! and `As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid][askubuntu.com/help](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! ;-)

Comment: Hi, this made my volume functions keys stop working :( so in my case, it stopped the problem but now I have no functionality.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. I tried these suggested gsettings resest, but to no avail; problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Even if not determining the cause of the problem, or fixing it, I will provide a workaround.

Go to *Settings* -> *Keyboard Shortucuts* -> *Sound and Media* -> *Volume down* and assign a shortuct.
Likewise for *Volume up*.
That will at least get you going.

I tried it with F2/F3 and it worked great. Of course, I am taking a keyboard shortcut that should be free and available, but that is probably a minor issue.

**Related**:

1. https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/solved-keyboard-hotkey-for-sound-volume/16911

Comment: Thanks. Great idea. This did work around the problem. I'd much rather be able to use the intended keys though. Thus I'll wait and hope for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the system is registering the keypress, you should be able to bypass this with `xmodmap`. Increasing and decreasing the volume is usually done in increments of 6% (unless you've changed this, which wasn't easily done on 18.04), so bypassing the default keypress — even with the same keys — may resolve the issue.

First things first: determine the keycodes for volume up and volume down.

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Use the `showkey` command to determine if the media keys are being detected and what the keycodes are:

   ```
   sudo showkey
   ```

   Once `showkey` is running, press the media keys. You may see something like this in the output:

   ```
   keycode 114 press
   keycode 114 release
   keycode 115 press
   keycode 115 release
   ```

   ***Note:** On my Lenovo Thinkpad,* `114` *is* <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, *and* `115` *is* <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. *You will probably see something different if you have dedicated keys for volume.*

   If you do not see any output, it means that the OS does not recognise the key presses at all and there's little you can do about it aside from searching for (or writing) a custom driver that will add support for your keyboard to Linux. Suffice it to say, if you don't see any input, you can skip the rest of this answer.
2. Write down the keycodes that you see for your media keys

Now we get to create a keyboard mapping file for `xmodmap`. Again, in Terminal:

1. Create a file that will contain your keyboard mappings in your home directory, such as `.xmodmap`:

   ```
   vi ~/.xmodmap
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use a different text editor. The use of* `vi` *here is more muscle memory than an implicit endorsement.*
2. Add the lines for your volume control:

   ```
   keycode 114 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioLowerVolume
   keycode 115 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to replace* `114` *and* `115` *with the keycode values that were recorded from* `showkey`.

   There are other XF86 keysyms that you might find useful, such as:

   | XF86 keysym | Action |
   | --- | --- |
   | XF86AudioMute | Mute the audio |
   | XF86AudioPause | Pause the currently playing audio (or restart) |
   | XF86AudioNext | Move to the next audio track |
   | XF86AudioPrev | Move to the previous track (or rewind the current track to start) |
   | XF86AudioStop | Stop the currently playing audio |

   My Lenovo does not have dedicated keys for previous and next, so I remapped <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for the purpose.
3. Save the file
4. Tell `xmodmap` to use the configuration file:

   ```
   xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
   ```

   ***Note:** There is no need to use* `sudo` *here.*
5. Try it out

So long as the OS can identify the keypresses for your audio keys, this should do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like perhaps you're answer is intending to make the volume buttons work *at all*. In my case, and I suppose in the OP's, the volume buttons already work correctly, except if held in for just a little bit, in which case the volume goes to the corresponding extreme (max or min). Is your answer intended to address this?